# Different or same variable in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure for a questionnaire that will update questions, possible answers and given answers. The problem I am having is if the question is a true/false or yes/no question, or a multiple choice question with 4 possible answers.

For each possible answer do I need a new variable name like, @PossibleANswert1, @PossibleAnswer2 or can I have just one?

I have this so far:

```
    BEGIN
    IF @Question_Type = 1 //a 1 means its a two answer question otherwise it will be a 4 answer question
    BEGIN

    Insert into QUESTIONS
    (QuestionType, Question_Text, Questionaire_ID, Filter)--
    Values
    (@Question_Type, @New_Question, @Questionnaire_ID, @Filter)

    select  @NewQuestion_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()-- 

    insert into Possible_Answers
    (Question_ID, Explanation_Required, Review_Required, Possible_Answer_Text, Question_Type)
    values 
    (@NewQuestion_ID, @Explanation,@Review,@Possible_Answer,@Question_Type), // true/false or yes/no
    (@NewQuestion_ID, @Explanation,@Review,@Possible_Answer,@Question_Type)

    insert into GIVEN_ANSWERS
    (Question_ID, Answer_Text, Explanation_Text, Sample_ID)
    values
   (@NewQuestion_ID, @Given_Answer, @Explanation_Text, @Sample_ID) 

   END
   ELSE 
   BEGIN
   Insert into Questions
   (QuestionType, Question_Text, Questionaire_ID, Filter)--
   Values
   (@Question_Type, @New_Question, @Questionnaire_ID, @Filter)

   select  @NewQuestion_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

   insert into Possible_Answers
   (Question_ID, Explanation_Required, Review_Required, Possible_Answer_Text, Question_Type)
   values 
   (@NewQuestion_ID, @Explanation,@Review,@Possible_Answer,@Question_Type), // mulitple choice
   (@NewQuestion_ID, @Explanation,@Review,@Possible_Answer,@Question_Type),
   (@NewQuestion_ID, @Explanation,@Review,@Possible_Answer,@Question_Type),
   (@NewQuestion_ID, @Explanation,@Review,@Possible_Answer,@Question_Type)

   insert into GIVEN_ANSWERS
   (Question_ID, Answer_Text, Explanation_Text, Sample_ID)
   values
   (@NewQuestion_ID, @Given_Answer, @Explanation_Text, @Sample_ID)
   END

   END
```

I'm fairly new to stored procedures so please feel free to call out any other mistakes or poor coding you see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a table user defined type. This will allow you to pass in any number of possible answers with any number of columns.

```
create type dbo.possible_answer as table(
  answer nvarchar(max),
  explaination nvarchar(max),
  review nvarchar(max)
);

create procedure dbo.create_question
 @QuestionType int,
 ....(Other params here)
 @PossibleAnswers dbo.possible_answer readonly
as
begin
....(some code)
   insert into Possible_Answers
    (Question_ID, Explanation_Required, Review_Required, Possible_Answer_Text, Question_Type)
    select @NewQuestion_ID,
    p.explaination,
    p.review,
    p.answer,
    @Question_Type
     from dbo.possible_answer p;
...(other code)
end
```

Comment: thank you, not sure why I got downvoted but thank you for answering, I'm going to try this and also a friend suggested an xml table with possible answers, so I'm going to look into both

Comment: Depending on your situation user defined types are usually easier to work with, but XML documents are more flexible.